# No Visual w/MP3 Colorbox Linking?

Tags: html, css, mp3, colorbox

I am scratching my head with - why ***nothing*** is appearing FOR :
 
[Mp3 'Original Rock' Audio Samples:] AUDIO SAMPLE NUMBER 1 **(First Link)**

The First Audio Sample Link "1" should link to this page (in the ColorBox): http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/audio/rockSample1.php

Working Page : http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/studio.php

Not Sure what the problem is.

```
<li>Mp3 'Original Rock' Audio Samples: <a href="http://glustik.com/dustreeproductions/audio/rockSample1.php" rel="example1">1</a>
```

I have checked my markup and I am not seeing anything wrong. (I might be overlooking something?)

Any help *or* suggestions are always helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is at ***www***.glustik.com, but that link is hardcoded for:
`http://glustik.com/dustreeproductions/audio/rockSample1.php`!

The [Same Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is blocking the load.

Consider using a relative link for your `href`s,
EG: `/dustreeproductions/audio/rockSample1.php` or `audio/rockSample1.php`.